# Can we make rabbitmq queue does not process message

Tags: queue, rabbitmq

I am using rabbitmq to send message between 2 services in micro-service.

I am having a problem. Can I setting the queue pause push message to consumer and continue to process message when I want? Or make consumer pause to get message out from queue and continue to get message when I want (But don't use the way stop/start consumer. Because I can't do it in my system.)?

If YES, can I do it by RabbitMQ Management HTTP API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do it. These are consuming policies. Maybe you can stop the publish.

Read also thread about: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/68-DPZN4b_Q